# control Objects contents

Tags: php, object

My question is banal question :P

Which is the equivalent control of count(array) related to Objects?

I mean how to control if Object contains somenthing or not :P

thx

Comment: By "contains somenthing" do you mean has properties that are not null?

Comment: nope :P i mean that contains properties (properties can be NULL itself)

Comment: as for array indexes when i do count(array) i check if and how many array indexes are present, while their values can be NULL or NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check:
`if (!empty($Object)) ...`

Comment: That's wrong: php > $a = new stdClass;
php > var_dump(empty($a));
bool(false)

Comment: @chelmertz You don't understand it. if some property of object will be not empty, result will be 'true'.

Comment: you are correct, but I think I am too :) The question is not very well defined. Consider the example: `php > $b = array('hello' => null);
php > var_dump(count($b));
int(1)`

Comment: @chelmertz yes, question is vague.

Comment: check comments now please , under my question :P

Answer (score 1):

By using [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

```
$o = new stdClass;
var_dump(count(get_object_vars($o)));

$o->marco = 'polo';
$o->han = 'solo';
var_dump(count(get_object_vars($o)));
```